# Is corda support migration from one node to another node with different network

Tags: corda

Is Corda provide solution for migrate data between different network i.e. migrate from ProdNet to UATNet or from UATNet to bootstrap network.
   The reason for doing this is for trying to experiment, analys or simulate problem on dev network.

The solution that I think about is to query all transaction and reissue it again but it's not flexible when I have to develop in another project, I've to develop this migrate again.

Comment: Satienpong - are you trying to take production data from your network and use that same data in UAT to test? If so that means you would want to keep the transaction history when moving data.

Comment: Hi Austin That's right so how could I move data from Prod to UAT without re-issue it again?

Answer (score 1):

In general, moving data between distributed ledger networks (including different Corda networks) is possible and even easy, but moving provenance (proof of correctness, and history) is hard.

This is because Corda 'states' (data records) have a history. Corda transactions don't update states  in-situ - they create new states, and mark the old ones as 'consumed'. This gives Corda its immutable quality. And the current states are linked to their predecessors through transaction chains, which give the states their provenance. And the transactions themselves are signed by direct participants, using a private key which is linked ultimately to a 'trust root' which provides a 'trust boundary' around all of the data on the ledger.

Different networks have different trust roots, and so the transactions which were regarded as valid in one network will not be regarded as valid in a different network. So the states, provenance and signatures cannot be exported from one network and imported to another, but the *data* can be exported by a participant and introduced / reissued on another network, where the participant is trusted in the target network.